# Two divs next to each other, the left one containing text, the right one an image

Tags: html, css

I try to set up a website with an image of a letter and a transcription. So basically:

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
  <div id="left-side" style="background-color:blue">
    Text
  </div>
  <div id="right-side" style="background-color:blue; min-width=50%; overflow: auto;">
    Image
  </div>
</div>
```

The image can either take up 50% of the width if the two divs are next to each other in the same line and 100% if the screen is too small so that the 2nd div is in the next line.

The text should not exceed a max-width of 750px and align to the right of the center page. If the divs are in two rows the text-div should be in the center.

This is what I have so far:

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
  <div id="left-side" style="background-color:blue">
    <div id="text" style="max-width:750px; min-width: 250px; background-color:orange; float:right; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
      This text should not be longer than 750px
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right-side" style="background-color:blue; max-width=50%;overflow: auto;">
    Image
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is: Dealing with the two variants:

1. text and image next to each other, each 50% of the width
2. text above and image below, both divs in the center and width=100%

Comment: Are you familiar with, or have you already looked at, using CSS media queries for this?  That is the usual way to introduce differences in behavior based on screen size, and I suspect you will end up needing them here.

Comment: Also, why is your `text` element inside the `left-side` element, if the text is actually supposed to be on the right side?  And same with the image, which is supposed to be on the left but is called `right-side'?

Comment: I have not expressed myself properly. The text should be in the left div, but aligned to the vertical center line. Anyhow: I now know that I have to use CSS-rules based on screen-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you want to use a @media rule based on the screen width.  Here is an example that would limit the image to 49% and show beside the text if the screen where 1500 px or wider.  (Eliminate the inline styling.)

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: red;
}

#left-side {
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: right;
    width: 49%;
}

#right-side {
    background-color: green;
}

#text {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 750px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: orange;
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
    #left-side {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #right-side {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
    }
}
```